# Trouble creating an apache storm application package for apache slider

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-storm

I am relatively new to apache storm and apache slider. I am trying to create a storm application package for slider.

So far:

1. I have gone to: http://slider.incubator.apache.org/docs/getting_started.html#downsample
2. There I get the following information in regards to creating a storm application:
   [image]
3. If I view the README.txt I get the following information:
   [image]
4. Whenever I run the code I get the following error:
   [image]
   What could be cause the error? Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance!